# autotools: showing optional features of nested packages

Tags: autotools

I am using nested packages with autotools, i.e.

```
  foo -
      |- configure.ac
      |- Makefile.am
      |- bar -
             |- configure.ac
             |- Makefile.am
```

Every package has its own set of optional features which are shown nicely by

```
$> cd foo; ./configure --help
   --enable-foo-feat1 
$> cd foo/bar; ./configure --help
   --enable-bar-feat1
```

However, I would like to see bar's optional features also from the foo level, i.e.:

```
$> cd foo; ./configure --help
   --enable-foo-feat1 
   --enable-bar-feat1
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
./configure --help=recursive
```

Should show options from nested packages.

Comment: Cool! But can I do anything on my main configure.ac to fore help=recursive in way.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know of that option. I did a quick search and didn't find anything similar.